# Is it a good practice to name the div id as the record id from the database table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, html

When there is a list of modifiable records that I want to show to users, usually I would name the id of each div as the record id of the database table. So that when a user click on a button on the list to perform certain action (eg. delete, modify etc.), by jQuery I can get the id of it by selecting the closest id in the div, and then I can know which record the user is selecting. Is it a good way to do so? What are your methods of doing this?

Comment: Depends on the situation but I tend to use data-id rather than id, just in case I need to put a actual ID on it

Comment: If you use forms with button, in my opinion, is better provide hidden field with id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name the ID whatever you wish, and it would be useful to have a record of the ID, but I'd go with this [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) solution:

```
<div data-id="14"></div>
```

That way, you don't have to name your ID something like `id_14` (this is because ID and class names must start with a letter).

To retrieve that in jQuery, simply do `$('div').data('id');`.

Comment: As I said, I would also recommend to use `data` attributes if there's gonna be duplicate ids on the same page. They also should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good way to do it. 
You could also use `data` attributes if you wish. Just make sure that those ids are unique for the whole page.

If you are going to show one user in more than one part of the page, then I would recommend you to use `data` attributes in order code properly and validate correctly.